# rich:fileUpload - files with non-english names

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

How can I use fileUpload to get files with non-english names?
Because right now when I use this component it doesn't get my files' names right.
Thanks.

Comment: Where and how exactly have you observed malformed characters? We need to exclude that presenter itself from being the cause (e.g. system.out.println or logger). And, how about values coming from regular input fields in same request?

Comment: It's a bug, unfortunately JSF and HTML use different default encodings.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the encoding like this:

```
correctFilename = new String(filename.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "utf-8")
```